# Connection to server failed from VBA but works from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have setup some queries in MS access that fetch data from a MS SQL server on the network. The queries work fine when I run them from MS access. However, when trigger the same query through VBA in Excel (need of my dashboard), then it says ODBC connection failed. I am not able to figure out what is broken in the process. All details below:

ODBC connection string in MS Access - set in the properties of the query

```
ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=xyz;UID=xyz_reader;PWD=xyzpassword;Network=DBMSSOCN;Address=xyz,1433
```

Connection string used in Excel VBA - this is used to trigger the odbc query in ms access

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & mydb.accdb
```

Error that I get

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
ODBC--connection to 'SQL Serverxyz' failed.
```

Comment: This is very helpful for situations where you are stuck - http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and there are a number of different connectors available and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA Connection is an ADODB connection so you need to add a references Tool>>References then add “Microsoft ActiveX Data Object Library”
Then use code like

```
Dim strConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set strConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=YourDATABASE;Data Source=YourServer"

strSQL = "Your Select statement”

strConn.Open
rs.Open strSQL, strConn
```

Now you have your values in record set. I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. however, my challenge is a bit different. i am pulling a large table from the server which i want to store in a local table in an ms access file. i can't connect to two databases (server & local ms access) and copy the data without keep an intermediate copy. therefore, to do this, i have setup an ODBC query in MS access that connects to the server (this works fine with the connection string I mentioned). then there is an equivalent blank table in ms access and i am running a query from excel-vba "insert into local_table select * from odbc_query" and then i get the error